# Cannot create a handler in laravel 5 using php artisan

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create an event handler using php artisan but it just won't work. It works perfectly with anything else for example event.

This is what I use in the cmd:

```
php artisan handler:event myhandler
```

This is the response:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "handler" namespace.
```

Comment: Handler function not exists. I think you need 'php artisan make:event myhandler'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `handler:event` was removed in 5.1, you can't use it anymore.

Maybe you're looking for [`php artisan event:generate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#generating-events-and-listeners) command.

Comment: Note that many Laravel helpers, such as the above, are not available in Lumen:
[link](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/events)